# What does „ладу, ладу“ mean in a song?

Tags: значения

I found it in one choir in Mussorgsky's Хованщина. The song goes like this:

> Плывёт, плывёт лебёдушка, **ладу, ладу**,
>
> плывёт навстречу лебедю, **ладу, ладу**.

etc.; the „ладу, ладу“ is regularly repeated at the end of every line. What does it mean? (And does it mean anything at all, or is it only an interjection like "fa la la" in English?)

E: Thank you both. Since they both are very good, I just accepted one randomly.

Comment: I suppose, nothing special. Something like "bla-bla-bla", just for the rhyme etc.

Comment: @Ramillies I'm not a native speaker of Russian and I have no evidence to support this, but when I first heard act IV, I perceived **ладу** as an interjection reinforcing the impression of the swan swimming/floating like a [**ладья**](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9B%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%8C%D1%8F_(%D1%81%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE)). The fact that none of the answers here mention anything of that sort means I was probably wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately **nobody can tell** you for sure what the word **ладу** in the refrain means. It has been mentioned though that it's not connected with the goddess. What is well known is the fact that such refrains are used in three types of folk songs:**spring, summer and wedding** songs. That means they were devoted to some customs and traditions and were khorovod songs which included some movement to the music. Those words helped the rythm or the beat.Used in other parts of the song the word **лада** meant **dear, beloved**.

Answer (score 5):

In this song (and in many other folk songs) it's just a refrain.

As for it's origin there are several opinions what "ладу", "ладо", "лада", "дид-ладо" means.

1. Nothing - it's just a refrain, like "fa-la-la" (I guess most scientists agree on this)
2. There is a word ладо/лада is also used in folk poetry meaning "beloved" or "spouse" (Ushakov's dictionary):

   > ЛА́ДА, лады (нар.-поэт.).
   >
   > 1. жен. Милая, возлюбленная, жена.
   > 2. муж. и жен. Милый, возлюбленный, мужск. Мой лада или моя лада.

I think this connection makes sense, because лебедь (swan) and лебёдушка (pen)  here are used to tell a "love story".

3. (rather popular, but incorrect) A refrain is based on a name of pagan goddess Lada (Лада) (or her male counterpart Lado (Ладо)). However most scientists think that this "goddes" was invented based on those refrains, since we don't know much about slavic mythology.

For more details see [Wikipedia](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9B%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0_(%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%8F)#.D0.9B.D0.B0.D0.B4.D0.B0_.D0.BA.D0.B0.D0.BA_.D0.BF.D0.B5.D1.81.D0.B5.D0.BD.D0.BD.D1.8B.D0.B9_.D1.80.D0.B5.D1.84.D1.80.D0.B5.D0.BD) (in Russian)
[English article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lada_(goddess)) is less detailed and says nothing about invention of a goddess name.

Comment: Слушайте ну вы серьёзно думаете что в песне богиня упоминается? В звательном, может падеже)))))

Comment: Нет не упоминается, есть люди, которые считают что слово "ладо" основано на имени богини.

Comment: А вот Фасмер пишет: «ла́да (м., ж.) "супруг, супруга", ладый "милый, любимый", др.-русск. лада "супруг" (СПИ), укр. ла́до, ла́да "супруг, супруга" (о лжебожестве Лада см. Потебня, РФВ 7, 226 и сл.), болг. ой ладо, ладо! – припев, ла́да "вторая дочь в семье, которая при обряде _ладу́ване_ идет за водой (свадебная церемония)", сербохорв. ла̏да "супруга".»

Comment: @Artemix ну может быть ))) вообще я никогда не задумывался как связано слово употребляемое в песне и слово ладный.

Comment: can it be vocative of lada?

Answer (score 0):

Addition:
Лад – old Russian word (maybe even Slavic word).
**Лад** is not only about love. 
**Лад** also means peace, harmony, order, consent. All connected with the word **лад** means something good: verb поЛАДить (make peace, get along (with), get on (with), come to an understanding), adjective ЛАДный (harmonious).